# Read Multiple Values from Firebase and place in a line graph

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1KA4.jpg)

In my firebase database I have test scores stored as seen in the linked picture.
I wish to read all of the percentages in my Android app and display them within Graph View.
I can successfully read one value from the database but struggle when it comes to displaying real time data in a graph.

Can anyone help. My attempted code is below, what should I do.

subjectRadar is above the username in the database.

```
    DatabaseReference radar = myRef.child("subjectRadar");



    radar.child(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
            DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            Double name = (Double) ds.child("mathematics").getValue();
            Float i = name.floatValue();
            Double name1 = (Double) ds.child("english").getValue();
            Float i1 = name1.floatValue();
            Double name2 = (Double) ds.child("history").getValue();
            Float i2 = name2.floatValue();
            Double name3 = (Double) ds.child("geography").getValue();
            Float i3 = name3.floatValue();



            LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {




                    new DataPoint(1, i),
                    new DataPoint(2, i1),
                    new DataPoint(3, i2),
                    new DataPoint(3, i3)


            });
            graph.addSeries(series);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a HashMap for this.

Push your data like this to your database:

```
HashMap subjects = new HashMap<String, Float>();
subjects.put("mathmatics", 1.3f);
subjects.put("english", 2.3f);
radar.child(username).setValue(subjects); //I think radar.child(username) is you Reference
```

Then you can retrieve your data like this:

```
radar.child(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap<String, Float> subjects  = (HashMap<String, Float>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            int i = 0;
            Iterator it = subjects.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                i++;
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                new DataPoint(i, pair.getValue());
                //Add this DataPoint to your Graph
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I still use this if the data is not pushed to the database, as I am uploading it via a google script?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you trying to do but sure, if you put Data into the HashMap then you can iterate over it and update the Graph this way, without having to send to the database and then retrieve it to update the graph. If this answers your question please mark as accepted answer :)

Comment: Iteration is a good idea, but we can't use float numbers on the graph :(